# How to get complete execution Information from os.popen

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to `pip install` some modules that other codes require. If `os.system("pip install module_name")` returns 1, I want to check the reason for the failure.

I've tried to use `os.popen()` to get some extra information, but `os.popen("pip install module_name").read()` returned only the first line of the execution information.

Does anyone happen to know how to get the complete information so that I can log this and fix it later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.popen` is not very powerful. Use `subprocess.Popen` and `communicate`:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("pip3 install module_name",
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

print("STATUS:", p.returncode)
print("STDOUT:", stdout)
print("STDERR:", stderr)
```